# how to return the minimum index of this array?

Tags: python, numpy, dask

```
ind_index = np.asarray([np.random.choice(40, 5, False) for i in range(5)])
fit = da.random.uniform(size=40, chunks=5)
parents_index = da.argmin(fit[ind_index], axis=1)
```

The result should be an array of shape (5,)(the minimum index of each row), instead it returns this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/skyolia/PycharmProjects/garbage/garbage.py", line 36, in 
<module>
parents_index = da.argmin(fit[ind_index], axis=1)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 
1383, in __getitem__
dsk, chunks = slice_array(out, self.name, self.chunks, index2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/array/slicing.py", 
line 158, in slice_array
dsk_out, bd_out = slice_with_newaxes(out_name, in_name, blockdims, 
index)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/array/slicing.py", 
line 180, in slice_with_newaxes
dsk, blockdims2 = slice_wrap_lists(out_name, in_name, blockdims, 
index2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/array/slicing.py", 
line 247, in slice_wrap_lists
index[where_list[0]], axis=axis)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/array/slicing.py", 
line 566, in take
plan = slicing_plan(chunks[axis], index)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dask/array/slicing.py", 
line 534, in slicing_plan
if chunk > 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

but the same code works well in pure numpy. Where is the problem ? many thx

Comment: Consider adding some of the traceback to your question

Answer (score 2):

You just call `argmin` on your given array `fit`, and optionally compute to show the result.

```
fit.argmin().compute()
```

You could also do:

```
import dask.array as da

da.argmin(fit).compute()
```

or

```
import numpy as np

np.argmin(fit).compute()
```

Remember that `fit` is *one* array of size 40. Perhaps you should describe in words what you are trying to achieve? Maybe the size should be a tuple like `(40, 5)` or something else like that?